# Installing a Personal Ado File

Tags: stata

I would like to install a personal ado file, but I am unable to figure out how.

I looked at Section 17.7 of the User Guide, and I created a folder called personal under C:\ado and dragged the file there.  Now I have the .ado under C:\ado\personal.

I then did

```
net set ado "C:\ado\personal"
adopath + "c:\ado\personal"
```

I have the following output:

```
[1]  (UPDATES)   "C:\Program Files\Stata12\ado\updates/"
[2]  (BASE)      "C:\Program Files\Stata12\ado\base/"
[3]  (SITE)      "C:\Program Files\Stata12\ado\site/"
[4]              "."
[5]  (PERSONAL)  "c:\ado\personal/"
[6]  (PLUS)      "c:\ado\plus/"
[7]  (OLDPLACE)  "c:\ado/"
[8]              "c:/ado/personal"
[9]              "c:\ado\personal"
```

However, when I do ssc install file.ado it says not found at ssc.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Removed `ado` tag. It means ActiveX Data Objects, not Stata `ado` files.

Answer (score 1):

You seem confused on several levels.

First off, `ssc` is a command for reading files from SSC. The syntax you seek is

`ssc inst` *packagename*

but in this case no package with the name `file.ado` (and none even with the name `file`) exists at SSC at this writing, so no surprise there.

If you didn't literally type `file.ado` then we can only guess wildly at what you did type, but in general it is as said package names (which won't include `.ado` as suffix) and not filenames that need to be typed. Almost always, a package contains at least two files and often many more. This form of installation is just a simple way of copying several files at once. (There are very occasional and unimportant exceptions.)

Second, `ssc` will by default install not in PERSONAL, but in PLUS. This is a matter of convention, but I can't think of a good reason to change it.

Third, and perhaps most important to you at this time, it seems that you already have this file on your computer. If so, you have absolutely no need to install it from SSC, an external source. Conversely, SSC has no interest in and no knowledge of private files on your computer.

Comment: Yes file.ado is simply an arbitrary name.  I have a file in my personal directory that I wrote.  Is just dragging the .ado sufficient for that?  And yes that is true, I never did ssc install file.ado, I should just clarified that file.ado is an .ado file and all this time I had been doing ssc intall file.  So in your third point, I have done all that I need to do?

Comment: As said, if you have a program file already, installing it from SSC is impossible if it does not exist there and irrelevant any way, unless you are updating. Your `net set` is irrelevant to files on  your own computer. You now have `c:\ado\personal` three times along your `adopath`: once is enough! But Stata should be able to see your program file, so you just need to try running it.

Comment: Ok I take back all of the ssc stuff.  It sounds like it was never necessary?  Is there a way to delete the superfluous personal paths?

Comment: That's what I am telling you. How to clean up your `adopath` is documented at `help adopath`. You will probably find the `adopath -` # syntax easier.